# Local nginx server requires reload every time dev server restarts

Tags: nginx, node.js

I have 2 local dev servers in node. One is a basic nextjs server and the other a very simple nodejs websocket server. I wanted to proxy both to get the both under the same port. I have the following nginx config:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 3002;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache off;
        }

        location /ws {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache off;
        }

        location /_next/webpack-hmr {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_cache off;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, if either the nextjs server or web socket server restart, then nginx will start returning a `502 Bad Gateway` page until I make nginx reload. What can I do here to make nginx reload automatically or try to reconnect to the server in this case? Are there any other better strategies here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like NGINX is not persisting connections with backends.

I modified you config based on the nginx docs and a blog they posted about websockets.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Try this and see if it works:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    sendfile off;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream node {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    upstream websocket {
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    server {

        listen 3002;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://node;
            proxy_set_header "Connection" "";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }

        location /ws {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

    }

}
```

If it still doesn't work, try adding `proxy_set_header "Connection" "";` to the websocket location.